# flask create table that has a link based on column value

Tags: python, flask

I've created the following Flask webapp (below). It outputs a simple dataframe on a page in a table format.

I'm trying to have the first column (`name`) in the table be clickable, and the link being created using the column `Linkdid` value as the suffix.

Concretely, Bob in the data frame would have a link of `client_details/111111` and each subsequent row will get its corresponding linkid and create the respective link in the following format: `client_details/{linkid}`:

```
<a href="#"  target="popup" onclick="window.open('client_details/{linkid}','name','width=600,height=400')">{{row_}}</a>
```

How would I grab the `linkid` column value in the loop to construct such a thing? Also I plan on hiding the linkid column at some point.

Here is what I have so far:

app.py

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, jsonify
import sys

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Bob','Carl','Doug','Edith','Ford','George']
                  , 'Amount': ['17','123','144','2','63','25']
                  , 'Quantity': ['147','1523','1144','542','5463','2135']
                  , 'Linkid': ['111111','2311231233','4142421','4124214','52435435','2535325']
                  })


@app.route("/")
def homePage():
      return render_template('index.html', column_names=df.columns.values, row_data=list(df.values.tolist()), zip=zip)
```

index.html

```
      <table id="customer_df" class="display">
        <thead class="text-primary">

          <tr>
            {% for col in column_names %}
            <th class="text-center">
            
              {{col}}
             
            </th>
            {% endfor %}
          </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for row in row_data %}
          <tr>
            {% for col, row_ in zip(column_names, row) %}

            {% if loop.index == 1 %} 
            <td><a href="#"  target="popup" onclick="window.open('client_details/','name','width=600,height=400')">{{row_}}</a></td>
            {% else %}

            <td>{{row_}}</td>
            {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}

         
        </tbody>
  
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pandas` methods, it will make it easier for you and with `formatters` that you can pass to [`df.to_html`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) method, you will end up with something similar to below:

1 - Create a `lambda` function for your `Linkid` column:

```
link_frmt = lambda x: '''<a href="#" target="popup" 
                      onclick="window.open('client_details/{0}', 
                      'name','width=600,height=400')">{0}</a>'''.format(x)
```

2 - Then you can pass the result of `df.to_html` to `render_template` like so:

```
render_template('index.html', 
                 table=df.to_html(
                       formatters={'Linkid':link_frmt},
                       escape=False
                                 )
                )
```

Also, at this stage, you can pass specific CSS styling with `classes='my_css_table` in `df.to_html` :

```
render_template('index.html', 
                 table=df.to_html(
                       formatters={'Linkid':link_frmt},
                       escape=False, 
                       classes='my_css_table'
                                 )
                )
```

3 - Finally in your template just do:

```
{{ table|safe }}
```

This will create the whole table and render it properly.

You can use CSS Styling for your df table:

```
table.dataframe, .dataframe th, .dataframe td {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align:left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
```